# Action bar items from a ViewPager fragment showing up after a delay

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, and my main activity has a ViewPager with three pages, all of them fragments. One of those fragments has an `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, and the action bar in the main activity is updated correctly.. sort of. Here's the method:

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu, com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    // A couple of other things
}
```

I'm using a custom `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    FragmentManager fm;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            accountFragment = Account.newInstance();
            return accountFragment;
        case 1:
            filesFragment = Files.newInstance();
            return filesFragment;
        case 2:
            transfersFragment = Transfers.newInstance();
            return transfersFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String makeFragmentName(int viewId, int index) {
        return "android:switcher:" + viewId + ":" + index;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return titleAccount;
        case 1:
            return titleFiles;
        case 2:
            return titleTransfers;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have no code at all in my activity that calls `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu`, so I assume the framework is checking the fragments' options menus for me, but I don't like how it does it. Here's what I mean:

[image: the problem]

Stock apps (Phone, People, etc) as well as some other apps do this correctly. That is, as soon as I fling to a page, that new page's menu items are displayed. But in mine, they are only displayed at the end of the swiping animation.

Here's something I've tried:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}
    });
```

This seems to do nothing.

Logging shows that `onPageSelected` is called right when I swipe to another page, which is when I **want** the items to update. Logging in my fragment's `onCreateOptionsMenu` shows that it is called only at the end of the animation, which has a considerable delay from when `onPageSelected` is called.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> Stock apps (Phone, People, etc) as well as some other apps do this correctly. That is, as soon as I fling to a page, that new page's menu items are displayed. But in mine, they are only displayed at the end of the swiping animation.

I cannot reproduce your behavior with Phone, on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.2. There, the action bar does not change until the new page is fully visible, regardless of whether it is a fling or swipe.

With Contacts, I see what you are seeing, in that the action bar changes when the finger lifts up, so on a fling, the change happens faster.

Frankly, I think that you're making a mountain out of a molehill. That being said, the only way I can see to replicate Contacts' behavior is to completely reimplement `FragmentPagerAdapter`, removing the `setMenuVisibility()` calls from `setPrimaryItem()`, then arrange to make those calls at what you feel is a more opportune time.

Comment: You're right about Phone, my mistake! I guess what bothers me is that I've seen plenty of third party apps (I just can't think of any) that don't have this issue. I feel like I'm missing one stupid little call somewhere.